# How to assign values into second dropdown based on first dropdown select box in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a dynamic adding of rows functionality and i have two dropdowns in each row. second dropdown values are populating from JSON and these values are mapped with first dropdown.

My requirement is onchange of the first dropdown I need to assign values to second dropdown in the same row. Here I am facing a problem that once I change value in the first dropdown then all the dropdown values in all the rows are getting changed.

Also I have added the Html code here for First Row dropdown.

```
<div class="firstdropdown">
    <select ng-change="getComponents">
        <option ng-repeat="kggrpItem in DesignGroupData track by $index" value={{kggrpItem}} ">{{kggrpItem}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="seconddrodown ">
   <select>
          <option ng-repeat="kggrpCmp in KgGroupCmpData"  value={{kggrpCmp}}>{{kggrpCmp}}</option>              
   </select>
</div>
```

For Example Controller Code....

```
$scope.getComponents = function(){
    for(i=0;i<jsonstring.length;i++){
      $scope.dropdownvaluesArr = jsonvalues
    }
    $scope.KgGroupCmpData = dropdownvaluesArr 
}
```

Please help me to fix the problem.

Comment: I thought U had a row which contains two dropdown. when first drpdwn value chng that updated value to be update in the second dropdwn on the same row Am I right r I am Out Of Path?

Comment: Can you create a working plunker??

Comment: Yes you are right sakthi,that is my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ng-change, Try ne-model it will change automatically second drop down value.

```
<div id="fistDropdown">
  <span>fistDropdown</span>
  <select ng-model="selected">
    <option ng-repeat="option in selectlist track by $index" value={{option.key}}>{{option.value}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="secondDropdown">
<span>SecondDropdown</span>
  <select ng-model="selected">
    <option ng-repeat="option in selectlist" value={{option.key}}>{{option.value}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

and pass selected value to ng-model like below

```
 $scope.selected = '3';
```

I attached fiddler url also please check it
[clone select box](https://jsfiddle.net/rsjeyakumar/16hqy86L/)